# SELECT FOR UPDATE in Hibernate and Oracle with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, hibernate, locking

I am having trouble getting SELECT FOR UPDATE to work in Hibernate and Oracle.

When I have two threads with one EntityManager per thread, the second thread seems to be able to read the same row as the first. I can see this by adding traces which show that the second thread reads the same row while the first is in between `query.getSingleResult()` and `entityManager.getTransaction().commit()` My expectation was that once a SELECT FOR UPDATE has been issued no one else should be able to read the same row until it is committed by the first thread. But this is not happening.

I can resort to an alternative implementation. What I want to achieve is only one process being able to read and update a row in an Oracle table so that it behaves like a queue given that the consumer processes can be in different machines.

Here is the minimum example of my code:

```
public MyMessage getNextMessage() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM MESSAGE WHERE MESSAGE_STATUS = 'Pending' AND rownum=1 FOR UPDATE OF MESSAGE_STATUS";
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, MyMessage.class);
    query.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    MyMessage msg = null;
    try {
        msg = (MyMessage) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException nodatafound) {
        // Ignore when no data found, just return null
    }
    if (msg != null) {
        msg.setMessageStatus("In Progress");
        entityManager.persist(msg);
    }
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    return msg;
}
```